# cron error bad minute + errors in crontab file can't install in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-14.04, cron

I have set my cron job and I am trying to set this new cron file path as default cron.

I try `crontab /path_to_the_file/cron_file.cron` but I get this error

> "/path_to_the_file/cron_file.cron":29: bad minute
>
> errors in crontab file, can't install.

My cron file contains:

```
43 1 * * *  /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/mysite/cron/file1.php 
29 0 * * *  /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/mysite/cron/file2.php 

23 1 * * *  /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/mysite/cron/file3.php 

#13 1 * * *  /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/mysite/cron/file4.php 
20 5 * * *  /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/mysite/cron/file5.php
```

Any idea? ...

Comment: I have tried to change my editor using `sudo update-alternatives --config editor ` but still I get the same error. I tried all options and tested

Comment: I get the same output using `hexdump cron_file.cron`. So what do you think how should I change configure the editor to not get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the cron file and delete the line breaks. There shouldn't be any breakline between the cron tasks.  Following this article [errors in crontab file, can't install](https://www.dougv.com/2006/12/fixing-a-bad-minute-error-message-when-trying-to-use-crontab-with-certain-unix-text-editors/) ...

```
17 1 * * *  /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/mysite/cron/file1.php
23 1 * * *  /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/mysite/cron/file2.php 
23 1 * * *  /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/mysite/cron/file2.php 
#13 1 * * *  /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/mysite/cron/file4.php 
20 5 * * *  /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/mysite/cron/file5.php
```

And it's working for me.

Comment: Spaces should be okay. I wasn't able to reproduce given the code above.

Comment: the point is, what you've given is unanswerable because the problem isn't given.

Comment: Because you never had this problem doesn't mean that any one won't have.

Comment: I think you misunderstand- given the question/problem, [it isn't reproducable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue,
Cron job to take backup of mysql
20 01 * * * /usr/bin/mysqldump -uusername -ppassword
 dbname > /storage path/storage naming convension.xyz

Error Message : 
"/tmp/crontab.EjlgjS/crontab":31: bad minute
errors in crontab file, can't install.
Do you want to retry the same edit? (y/n) y

Solution which worked for me is :
When I remove space from second line and made complete cronjob into single line.